# ADODB.Stream object can't be created

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-11, activex

For one of our clients we are building an (internal) web application and are using ActiveX in IE11 to create some temp files.

Now on my development machine the solution I have built works fine.
64-bit Windows 7 - IE11 - .NET Framework 4.7.1
However on our production machines, the ADODB.Stream Object can't be created.
32-bit Windows 7 - IE11 - .NET Framework 4.6.0

Assume that the IE11 Safety settings are correctly configured, as they are the same as on the development environment.

When I install .NET Framework 4.7.1 on one of the production machines the ADODB.Stream object can suddenly be created without problems.
Unfortunately it is not an option to roll out an update to the .NET Framework on all of the production machines because of other dependancies.

I am wondering if anyone could tell me if there is a certain specific part of that Framework that we could manually install on our production environment to fix this issue. Is there a DLL file we could manually install somewhere, or is there something else I am missing?

JS Code:

```js
try {
  outStream = new ActiveXObject('ADODB.Stream');
  outStream.Type = 2;
  outStream.CharSet = 'iso-8859-1';
  outStream.Open();
  outStream.WriteText(content);
  outStream.SaveToFile(tmpFilePath, 2);
  outStream.Close();
}
catch (e) {
  alert("An error occurred trying to create tempfile: " + e.description);
}
```

If not is there an alternative to the ADODB.Stream object that can write binary files to the filesystem. The [FileSystemObject](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us//library/z9ty6h50(v=vs.84).aspx) doesn't seem to be able to.

Additionally a lot of questions here about ActiveX seem to have the general advice: "Don't use ActiveX". We are aware of the security issues, however it is in a completely local, secure environment and the client insists on having this functionality.

Any help would be appreciated at this point.